# Particles in curved space-time and group representation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, elementary-particles, qft-in-curved-spacetime

It is [well-known](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0611263), that **particles in Minkowski space** can be constructed as **unitary projective representations of the Poincaré group**, i.e. isometry group of Minkowski space:
$$M_d= \frac{Poincare_d}{SO(1,d-1)}$$

Is such construction for another maximal-symmetric space-times:

$$AdS_d = \frac{SO(2, d-1)}{SO(1, d-1)}\;\;\;\;\;\; and \;\;\;\;\;\; dS_d =\frac{SO(1,d-1)}{SO(1, d-2)}$$

For example, in AdS there is special representation -- **singeleton**. It's field representation are pure gauge degrees of freedom and do not propogate. However any massless field in AdS can be constructed by taking the product of two of them.

Comment: related: [Unitary representations of the diffeomorphism group in curved spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100921/84967), [Why don't we consider the representation theory of isometry groups of space-times in curved QFT?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/305757/84967).